# Set directive isolated scope parameters in different ways

Tags: angularjs

This is my directive definition:

```
myApp.directive('myCategory', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      category: '=someCategory',
    },
    templateUrl: 'category.html',
    controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
  };
}])
```

Sometimes I know what is the name of my category and want to use my directive in following way:

1. `<my-category some-category="flowers"></my-category>`

But in some cases the category depends on some dynamic data and I want to use function from my controller:

2. `<my-category some-category="getCategory()"></my-category>`

Is this possible?

Actyally, it doesn't work for me...in the my directive controller, CategoryCtrl:

in case 1: `$scope.category is undefined`

in case 2: $scope.category is the name which has been returned by function and it is ok

Can anyone help me with this? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In case one, `flowers` is interpreted as an attribute of the scope of the enclosing controller. If you want to pass the literal string "flowers", you need to use

```
some-category="'flowers'"
```